# Stuck working on CSS width/float for header

Tags: html, css, header, css-float, width

I'm kinda stuck on the CSS for a home project I'm doing. Currently I'm working on a header, or 'top menu bar'. On each side of the viewport there are a button or two with a fixed px dimension. These L and R side div's are both set to float L and R, and are set as display:block;.

Now what I'm trying to get is that the 'header-center'-div will float on the same line in the center between these L and R div's. And all content within it should be centered as well. The last thing I'm trying to do is the max. width of the center div  may (dynamically) not be more then what is left of the viewport width minus what is used for the L and R div (so everything stays on the same height).

How can I get the result I want for this??

```
<header>
 <div id="header-left"></div>
 <div id="header-center"></div>
 <div id="header-right"></div>
</header>

#header-left {
 width: 160px;
 height: 80px;
 display: block;
 float: left;
}

#header-center {
 height: 80px;
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#header-right {
 width: 240px;
 height: 80px;
 display: block;
 float: right;
}
```

Comment: Share your CSS code.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can solve your problem

```css
header{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#header-left { 
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #f00;
}

#header-center {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #0f0;
}

#header-right {
  width: 240px;
  height: 80px;
  display: table-cell;
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div id="header-left">Left</div>
 <div id="header-center">Center</div>
 <div id="header-right">Right</div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested Answer:

```
<!Doctype html>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0;
            width:100%;
        }

        #header-left,
        #header-center,
        #header-right{
            float:left;
            text-align:center;
            padding-top:10px;
            padding-bottom:10px;
        }

        #header-left,
        #header-right{
            width:10%;
            background:rgb(255,0,0);
        }

        #header-center{
            width:80%;
            background:rgb(0,0,255);
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="header-left">Content</div>
            <div id="header-center">Content</div>
            <div id="header-right">Content</div>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```